# AWS IOT: Read Thing Shadow

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

the aws iot javascript sdk is a bit abstruse.
i have a thing shadow, that i just want to read out. no biggie (i thought)

i don't know what functions i need to use, to just read out the thing shadow data.
The Connection to AWS works fine, but whatever im trying to do, i don't receive any data.

heres my code so far:

```
var awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');

var name = 'Testthing';

var shadow = awsIot.thingShadow({
   keyPath: 'cert/privkey.pem', 
  certPath: 'cert/cert.pem',
    caPath: 'cert/rootCA.crt',
  clientId: "testapp",
      host: "xxx"
});


shadow.on('connect', function() {
  shadow.register('Testthing'); 
});

shadow.get(name, data) { // something like this..
  console.log(data);
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by myself. To readout your current Thing Shadow use this Code:

```
var awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');
var name = 'yourThingName';

var thingShadows = awsIot.thingShadow({
   keyPath: 'cert/privkey.pem', 
  certPath: 'cert/cert.pem',
    caPath: 'cert/rootCA.crt',
  clientId: "YourAppName",
      host: "YourHostLink"
});



thingShadows.on('connect', function() {
    thingShadows.register(name, {}, function() {
       thingShadows.get(name);
    });
});

thingShadows.on('status',  function(name, stat, clientToken, stateObject) {
  console.log('received '+stat+' on '+name+': '+JSON.stringify(stateObject));
});
```